# Can Xcode's PNG modifications when creating .car asset catalog be disabled?

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

So, I have run into a strange issue with the way that Xcode creates Assets.car in an iOS app. It seems that build process adds headers to every PNG to indicate the colorspace. I have an example PNG stored as grayscale that is 4 bytes of data (the PNG is 68 bytes), but the generated PNG in the Assets.car is 3395 bytes. What exactly is going on here? Well, pngcheck tells the story:

```
pngcheck -v test_Normal.png
File: test_Normal.png (3395 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    4 x 1 image, 8-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
  chunk iCCP at offset 0x00025, length 3315
    profile name = kCGColorSpaceGenericGrayGamma2_2
    compression method = 0 (deflate), compressed profile = 3281 bytes
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x00d24, length 11
    zlib: deflated, 256-byte window, superfast compression
  chunk IEND at offset 0x00d3b, length 0
```

Compare this to the original PNG:

```
pngcheck -v test.png 
File: test.png (68 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    4 x 1 image, 8-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x00025, length 11
    zlib: deflated, 256-byte window, fast compression
  chunk IEND at offset 0x0003c, length 0
```

This iCCP PNG chunk seems to correspond to the following file, once zlib compressed.

```
'/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile.icc'
```

Is there no way to disable this automatic PNG modification when images are written into a car file? With a lot of small PNG images this will inflate the installed app size.

I did additional testing of 24 BPP sRGB tagged pixel data, and while this seems hard to believe, the Apple asset catalog PNG encoding process is actually silently changing input PNG data so that it is no longer lossless. Here is an example image [image: 4x4 PNG] that corresponds to the following hex data:

```
0x020100 0x050403 0x080706 0x0B0A09 
0x0E0D0C 0x00000F 0x000000 0x000000 
0x000000 0x000000 0x000000 0x000000 
0x000000 0x000000 0x000000 0x000000
```

This image data is fine up until you put it into a asset catalog, the xcode build process changes the PNG pixel data to the following:

```
0x020100 0x050403 0x080706 0x0B0A09
0x0E0D0C 0x00010E 0x000000 0x000000
0x000000 0x000000 0x000000 0x000000
0x000000 0x000000 0x000000 0x000000
```

Note how the pixel at (1,1) was changed from 0x00000F -> 0x00010E by the asset catalog creation process.

Comment: Somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406749/how-can-i-modify-create-car-assets-file-located-inside-an-ios-sdk?rq=1